# QML prevent signal propagation

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to prevent signal from propagating to other QML?
Example:

```
//Base.qml
Item {
    signal backClicked()

    //handles the back button
}

//Test1.qml
Base {
    onBackClicked: console.log("BACK FROM TEST1")
}

//Test2.qml
Test1 {
    onBackClicked: console.log("BACK FROM TEST2")
}
```

When i click the back button the output is the following:
"BACK FROM TEST1"
"BACK FROM TEST2"

Is it possible to decide when to propagate the backClickedSignal() to Test2?

Comment: No, because you can't even depend on the order that they occur in. You can stop events from propogating, but not signals.

Comment: You can add a new signal in Test1 and add its signal handler in Test2. You can trigger this new signal from `onBackClicked` in Test1 when you want to propagate the info to Test2.

Comment: @ArunKumarB that's a good idea, thank you.